# Using ajax to update list.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am currently trying to update a list of duties after the user has posted a new duty. I am trying to use Ajax doing this. However I am not shure how to use ajax for posting to my controller and then add to my list. How do I use my datafield in my ajax method and how do I update my list?

My controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        Public ActionResult CreateDuty(PartialViewModel d)
{
        db.DutiesTable.Add(d.OneDuty);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    pv.DutyList = db.DutiesTable.ToList();

                    return View("Index");
    }
```

My Ajax method:

```
<script>
    $('#getDuty').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/CreateDuty",
            data: {d : d}
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data + status);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information.
Where did d come from and what is it (javascript).

For your EF code I assume DutiesTable does NOT contain PartialViewModel's so there is a mapping that needs to happen there between the view model and EF model classes.

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult CreateDuty(DutyViewModel d)
{
    Duty newduty = new Duty(){ /*map values from d to fields here*/}
    db.Duties.Add(newduty);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index");
}
```

Once you have your data posting over the controller and saving with EF you need to decide on if your javascript needs a copy of the updated entity (mapped back to a PartialViewModel most likely or if a simple success/fail message is enough and do what it needs to on that side.
I don't know what you mean here: "and then add to my list" - what list?

Comment: Do you mean the d in my Ajax method in the data field? I was hoping this would be the same d as in the controller. However I am not quite shure how to use Ajax. Where does the "mappedduty" variable come from? By list i mean the list where all of the duties are added. That would be the DutyList. Is it possible to update it so that a new duty would be added to the top of it?

Comment: I am going to update my answer with some stuff renamed to make it more obvious.

Comment: Does the update help? The crux is that the view model class is not the same as the duty class. You have to map between the EF class for the table and the view model for the UI. There are several frameworks that can trivialize that for you, most popular being automapper.